# views display restricted number of results based on nid

Tags: 7, views

Is it possible to create a view which would show only 3 rows. Based on curent node (nid) show result before current row and show one row after this row.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the `Node: Nid` filter.

1. Add the `Node: Nid` filter
2. Select **Operator** > **equal to** > **Is between** and then select the nid before your node as the **Min** and the nid after your node as the **Max**.

Comment: The view should be dynamic - based on current node, so putting certain nid as min/max would not help.